# Paying with property wild cards, can they be placed anywhere?

Tags: monopoly-deal

In Monopoly Deal, when paying rent with a property wild card, can the opponent receiving the card place it anywhere in their property collection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Property cards - including wild cards - can be arranged however the receiving player sees fit, at any point during their turn. For two-colour wildcards, there is no restriction that these have to remain in the orientation that they were originally played.

Note that ten-colour wildcards have zero monetary value so should not be used to pay rent -[see Property FAQ points 3 and 4 on monopolydealrules.com](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=property).